# Decompile Requirejs optimized file

Tags: javascript, requirejs, reverse-engineering, decompiling, uglifyjs

Once a js application (constructed of many separate modules) gets optimized (using the [Requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) optimization tool to put the whole code into one single file);   is it possible to decompile/unuglify back the file into separate modules as it used to be before optimization?

The use case would be a scenario (even though it is hard to happen) where you have lost your source code but have access to optimized js file.. Are there any ways/methods out there to separates the modules automatically into js files instead of doing it manually?

Comment: I have the same issue right now. I'm planning to write my own decompiler: I'll let you know if I finish it.